# How to allow Expo to send and receive to localhost?

Tags: http, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo SDK and Expo app on my iPhone 6 to build a React Native app. I need to console.log from my REST api and would like to do so from localhost before deploying to a server. Unfortunately, iOS (as well as Android, I've been hearing) block unsecure connections which, of course, include localhost. For those building React Native apps without Expo, there are the options of circumnavigating the aforementioned stricture natively from the iOS and Android folders. But how do we do the same thing with Expo? I read Charlie Cheever's (of the Expo team) post that these strictures are lifted in Expo but I've found that not to be the case, and his last post on the subject was back in August 2017 - https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-enable-ios-http-requests/1794
Hence, I considered posting this to Expo forums but imagined I might not get anywhere with that. Obviously, there is no need to provide code for this question. Many people seem to be experiencing this exact problem so I do hope this post receives an answer.

Comment: I think you need `expo eject`

Comment: @hongdevelop I meant to say above, without ejecting, of course.